# What is 'this' before an object is instantiated in js?

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I don't understand the following:

```
var x = function() {
    this.foo="foo";
    return function() {
        this.bar = "bar";
        return foo+bar;
    };
}(); // returns inner

alert(x()); // 'foobar', so both 'this' variables are set
alert(x.bar); // undefined - but wasn't it used correctly?
alert(new x().bar); // ok, works
```

My assumption was that a default 'this' scope/variable-map is generated and used the first time, and then when 'new' is called, a new object (function?) with a new 'this' is sent through and returned. Or, perhaps x isn't a proper object? But then, how does 'this' end up being set and used to make 'foobar'?

What do I need to know to understand this?

Comment: Read all the answers and follow the links to past discussions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First let's go over some fine points of JavaScript, then we can deal with your example.

#### Function's context

One point of misunderstanding is a context. Every function is called in a context, which is available using a keyword `this`. Let's write a function we can use to inspect contexts:

```
var probe = function(){
  // if the context doesn't have a name, let's name it
  if(!this.name){
    this.name = "lumberjack";
  }
  // print the name of my context
  console.log(this.name);
};
```

Here we go:

```
name = "global!";

// when we call a function normally it still have a context:
// the global context
probe(); // prints: global!

var ctx = {name: "ctx"};

// we can set a context explicitly using call()
probe.call(ctx); // prints: ctx

// we can set a context explicitly using apply()
probe.apply(ctx); // prints: ctx

// it is set implicitly, if we call a function as a member
ctx.fun = probe;
ctx.fun(); // prints: ctx

// or we can create a brand new object and set it as a context:
// that's what "new" does
var t = new probe(); // prints: lumberjack

// let's sum it up:
console.log(name);     // prints: global!
console.log(ctx.name); // prints: ctx
console.log(t.name);   // prints: lumberjack
```

That's why it is so easy to mess up and fall down inadvertently to the global context.

#### Returning value in constructor

Many people are confused when they see a constructor returning a value. It is legal. Constructor can return an object, a function, or an array. This value is going to be used as an instance. The old instance is going to be discarded.

```
var myClass = function(){
  // if it is called as a constructor, "this" will be a new instance
  // let's fill it up:
  this.a = 42;
  this.b = "Ford";
  this.c = function(){ return "Perfect"; };
  // done? let's discard it completely!
  // and now for something completely different...
  return {
    owner: "Monty Python",
    establishment: "Flying Circus"
  };
};
var t = new myClass();
alert(t.owner + "'s " + t.establishment);
```

As expected it shows "Monty Python's Flying Circus".

If a constructor returns something else (e.g., a number, a string, the null, the undefined) the returned result is going to be discarded and the old instance will be used.

#### The example

Your example is hard to understand mostly because of the way it was written. Let's simplify it by rewriting.

First let's deal with the `x`:

```
var x = function() {
  this.foo = "foo";
  return function() {
    this.bar = "bar";
    return foo + bar;
  };
}(); // returns inner
```

As we can see the anonymous function (the 1<sup>st</sup> `function`) is executed immediately, so we can inline it:

```
// next assignment can be simplified because
// top "this" is window or the global scope
//this.foo = "foo"; =>
foo = "foo";
x = function() {
  this.bar = "bar"; // this line depends on its context, or "this"
  return foo + bar; // this line uses global "foo" and "bar"
};
```

So at the end we have two global variables: `foo` (a string) and `x` (a function).

Now let's go over the 1<sup>st</sup> alert:

```
alert(x()); // 'foobar', so both 'this' variables are set
```

Again, let's inline `x()`:

```
// next assignment can be simplified because
// top "this" is window or the global scope
//this.bar = "bar"; =>
bar = "bar";
// at this moment both global "foo" and "bar" are set
alert(foo + bar); // => "foo" + "bar" => "foobar"
```

The 2<sup>nd</sup> alert is equally simple:

```
alert(x.bar); // undefined - but wasn't it used correctly?
```

It doesn't need much rewriting. `x` is a function, we didn't add any properties to it, so `x.bar` is undefined. If you add it, you can see results:

```
x.bar = "bar2";
alert(x.bar); // bar2
```

The 3<sup>rd</sup> alert demonstrates JavaScript's OOP in action:

```
alert(new x().bar); // ok, works
```

(A side note: it works only because you ran `x()` first, otherwise it blows up because `bar` is undefined).

Let's rewrite it like that:

```
var t = new x();
alert(t.bar); // bar
```

Now let's analyze the constructor. It has two statements: an assignment, and a return. The latter is ignored because it returns a string. So we can rewrite it like that:

```
x = function(){
  this.bar = "bar";
};
var t = new x();
alert(t.bar); // bar
```

I hope it all looks easy now.

Comment: This is a very helpful tutorial (though the first inline steps are hard to follow without knowing how 'this' works). Thank you!

Comment: I rearranged my original post so it flows more logically. Thank you for the suggestion how to make it better!

Answer (score 4):

That's the major complain of the [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/new_Operator) operator...

That operator creates a new object that inherits from the prototype of the operand constructor function, and then it calls the function, assigning the new object to `this`.

If you forget to use the new operator when calling a constructor function, you get instead normal function call, and `this` is bound to the global object (`window`) instead of to a new object.

Your function will be appending global variables whenever it uses `this` attempting to initialize its own instance.

In your example the global object ends up with two new variables:

```
window.foo
window.bar
```

Because of that some people prefer [prototypal inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) instead of the pseudo-classical approach.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question you ask in your title: `this` will reference the global object.

Keep in mind, `this` does not behave in JavaScript as it does in languages like Java or C++; it's used purely for context, and will not necessarily reference the same sort of object every time a given function is called. [From the MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/this_Operator):

> There are four ways `this` can be passed
>   *[...]*
>   If none of the above ways are used, the global object is passed as the context object, e.g., when this occurs at top-level outside of any constructor, or when a function is called without being called as a method of an object, as in `func(arg1, arg2)`.

For answers to the rest of your question, please see: [**Just when I think I finally understand Javascript scope…**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652372/just-when-i-think-i-finally-understand-javascript-scope)

Answer (score 3):

As Shog9 said, this is not the same as normal scoping like you see in Java, etc.

AFAIK Javascript uses dynamic scoping, like Common LISP/eLisp does, and not lexical scoping like Scheme/Lisp-1 does.