# How Do I Access Event Listeners on an instance of class?

Tags: javascript

Seeking to create an event handler that registers a callback and iterates based on the event.

An early, working example is something like this:

```
var elt = document.getElementById("square"),
      clickCount = 0;

  // call a priviledged method with access to prviate vars from 
  // outer scope
  var count = function () {
    clickCount += 1;
    alert("you clicked me " + clickCount + " times!");
  };

  elt.addEventListener("click", count, false);
```

Now I want to actually write something js I could use. Here is the current construction:

```
//Create a class object
function CountMe () {

 //privately scoped variables
  var clickCount = 0;

 //methods on 'class' CountMe
  this.countClick = function () {
    //who's context am I in?
    this.addCount();
    alert("you clicked me " + clickCount + " times!");
  };

  this.addCount = function() {
    clickCount += 1 
  };
};

// Create an instance of countMe class
var clickMe = new CountMe();

//Add an event listener for clicks 
document.getElementById("square").addEventListener("click", clickMe.countClick ,false)
```

The error I receive is `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<CountMe> has no method 'addEventListener'`
Given an html page like this:

```
<html>
<body>
 <div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:red;" id="square">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My questions are:

- How should this be constructed so `onclick` events function as they do in the first method?
- In the method `countClick` what context is the nested this in? The instance of the `CountMe` class I suspect, just want someone else's take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should this be constructed so onclick events function as they do in the first method?
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'addEventListener'

That's obcously the reason. You need to add the event listenere to a DOM element, so you could do for example:

```
var clickMe = new CountMe();
document.getElementById("square").addEventListener("click", clickMe.countClick, false);
```

The variable `elt` is, as correctly commented, privately scoped and cannot be accessed from outside. That means you just should move the add-process into the constructor (if the element is determinable), or drop it at all.

> In the method countClick what context is the nested this in? The instance of the CountMe class I suspect, just want someone else's take.

That depends on the calling. With your code

```
clickMe.countClick();
```

the instance `clickMe` would be the context, but when the function is called as an event listener the DOM element will be the context. See MDN's overview for the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). You can use a closure-scoped variable to hold a reference to the actual instance, as for example described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081499/accessing-an-objects-property-from-an-event-listener-call-in-javascript?lq=1) (there are many questions about that).

Three possible quick-fixes:

- `domel.addEventListener("click", clickMe.countClick.bind(clickMe), false)`
- `domel.addEventListner("click", function(){clickMe.countClick();}, false)`
- `var that=this; this.countClick=function(){ that.addCount(); alert(); };`

Comment: I will give the links a look. I've updated my code example and now I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'addCount'`. Can you fiddle a working answer based on your comment?

Comment: Yes, that's now the problem/feature that the context is the DivElement not the CountMe instance.

Comment: I have outlined the possible solutions, though probably you would have found and understood them yourself when reading about the problem.

Comment: you're definitely right. I am coming from a different language and context functions a bit differently