# JavaScript's Array call and functions fail inside Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this code:

```
function Keyboard() {

    this.log = $('#log')[0];
    this.pressedKeys = [];

    this.bindUpKeys = function() {
        $('body').keydown(function(evt) {
            this.pressedKeys.push(evt.keyCode);

            var li = this.pressedKeys[evt.keyCode];

            if (!li) {
                li = this.log.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
                this.pressedKeys[evt.keyCode] = li;
            }

            $(li).text('Down: ' + evt.keyCode);
            $(li).removeClass('key-up');
        });
    }

    this.bindDownKeys = function() {
        $('body').keyup(function(evt) {
            this.pressedKeys.push(evt.keyCode);

            var li = this.pressedKeys[evt.keyCode];

            if (!li) {
                li = this.log.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
            }

            $(li).text('Up: ' + evt.keyCode);
            $(li).addClass('key-up');
        });
    }

}
```

I get these errors:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.pressedKeys.push')
```

It doesn't matter what I want to do with the Array, it just keeps giving me access errors, as if it doesn't exists inside the prototype.

What am I doing wrong? :( I'm just accessing the array as any other value inside the prototype). Are there problems with objects inside objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that inside the event handler `this` is not what you think. You can bind the event handler function with the `bind` method (or, since it looks like you're using jQuery, [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)):

```
this.bindUpKeys = function() {
    var that = this;
    $('body').keydown($.proxy(function(evt) {
        //Use `this` as normal inside here
    }, this));
}
```

Or you can store a reference to `this` outside of the event handler e.g.

```
this.bindUpKeys = function() {
    var that = this;
    $('body').keydown(function(evt) {
        //Use `that` instead of `this` in here
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work :). I was totally thinking out of scope. I'm used to using programming languages more as of lately than scripting. I was totally ignoring the scope in this matter. Thanks again ^^

Answer (score 0):

> as if it doesn't exists inside the prototype.

No, it does.

> I'm just accessing the array

That's what you don't. `this` does not point to your `Keyboard` instance inside an event listener.

When the function is called as an event listener the DOM element will be the context (jQuery does that, too). See MDN's overview for the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). You can use a closure-scoped variable to hold a reference to the actual instance, as for example described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081499/accessing-an-objects-property-from-an-event-listener-call-in-javascript?lq=1) (there are many questions about that).

Possible quick-fixes:

- `$('body').keydown( (function(){...}).bind(this))`
- `var that=this; $('body').keydown(function(){ that.pressedKeys...; });`