# Javascript function as callback

Tags: javascript, function

The following script produces "Hello", "undefined", "Hello" message boxes:

```
function action(callback) {
  window.setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}

var obj = { 
  text: "Hello", 
  f: function() { window.alert(this.text); } 
};

obj.f(); // Line 1
action(obj.f); // Line 2
action(function() { obj.f(); }); // Line 3
```

I looking for explanation why the line marked as "Line 2" produces "undefined" output.

Comment: Best answers on `this` topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80084/in-javascript-why-is-the-this-operator-inconsistent/80478#80478 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541167/what-is-the-rationale-for-the-behavior-of-the-this-keyword-in-javascript/542060#542060

Comment: The first reference is really good one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in JavaScript, `this` is not bound to the method (like in python). Line 2 results in just the function being called, and `this` is undefined or not `obj`

Answer (score 2):

When you call line2: You are only passing the function into the parameter. Since you are only passing the function, not the whole object, when it is called, `this` in the function does not refer to `obj`, thus making `this.text` undefined.

Comment: Actually, _this_ in that context means the global object - in this case, _window_

Answer (score 1):

Alot of JS libraries do something like this:

```
if (!Function.prototype.context) {
    Function.prototype.context = function (object) {
        var fn = this;
        return function () { return fn.apply(object, arguments); };
    };
}
```

To be able to pass/bind `this` to a handler.
So in your case you can do smthg like this

```
action(obj.f.context(obj));
```

and receive your 'Hello'. And yes, this is a general way to do something you done in step 3.

Answer (score 0):

The second one you pass a function with no scope so **this** becomes the highest object in the scope chain. The third way you create a closure and call f on the object directly which leaves **this** with the proper scope.